# Learning SQL Query Not Working Properly

Tags: mysql, sql, derby

I'm working on a problem where I need to determine who the pitcher with the most wins is for each MLB team.  I am using derby to do this.

Here is what I have...W is for wins

```
 SELECT one.teamID
 FROM Pitching one
 Where (one.W >= ALL
    (SELECT two.W
    FROM Pitching two
    Where (two.teamID = one.teamID) 
           AND (one.playerID < two.playerID)));
```

This doesn't produce the correct results.  Could someone instruct me on where I went wrong and what a better approach might be?  Thank you.

Comment: What is the expected and actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
AND (one.playerID < two.playerID)
```

It accepts players with a higher ID but a lower win rate, which is probably not what you want.